# Metaprogrammed Scope in Module causing NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

I have an HR system with a Person model and a Field model.  Person has some attributes which are stored in regular database columns, and some which can be added dynamically.

The Field table has a record for every database column on the people table.  These are system required fields. Admins may add as many (non system required) fields as they like when configuring the application. They can also set properties for the fields, eg whether they are mandatory.

For non-mandatory fields, admins may like to add a widget to the user's homepage which shows how many people have this attribute missing.  Eg an admin may add a :personal_email field, and a widget which shows how many people have not had that field entered.

Fields can be added to the application at runtime, and scopes are used to filter the people table for missing records.  This is all done using the PersonField module.  When a new field is added and a widget is requested, the application produces the error `` NoMethodError: undefined method `missing_personal_email' for #<Person::ActiveRecord_Relation> ``.

On restarting the rails server the error does not appear. I thought this may be to do with cache_classes however it happens in development where it is false.  How could I refactor the PersonField module to avoid this issue?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PersonField
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base   
    enum field_type: {:boolean => 1, :integer => 2, :string => 3, :date => 4, :time => 5, :datetime => 6, :float => 7, :decimal => 8, :reference => 9, :any => 10, :email => 11, :phone => 12, :text => 13, :currency => 14, :postcode => 15}
    enum widget:  { :not_set => 0, :missing => 1, :not_missing => 2 }

    scope :widget, -> { where.not(widget: 0) }
    scope :system_required, -> {where(system_required: 1)}
    scope :not_system_required, -> {where(system_required: 0)}
end

module PersonField
    included do
        typed_store :data do |s|
            Field.active.each do |f|
                case f.field_type.to_sym
                when :integer, :reference
                    s.integer f.name.to_sym
                when :string, :text, :email, :phone, :postcode
                    s.string f.name.to_sym
                when :datetime
                    s.datetime f.name.to_sym
                # etc for all field types
                else
                    s.any f.name.to_sym
                end
            end
        end
    end

    Field.active.system_required.widget.uniq.each do |f|  
       scope "#{f.widget}_#{f.name}", -> { where("people.#{f.name} IS NULL") } 
    end

    Field.active.not_system_required.widget.pluck(:name).uniq.each do |f|
       # EG for :personal_email field this gives the SQL condition: people.data NOT LIKE '%personal_email%' OR people.data LIKE '%personal_email: \n%' 
       scope "#{f.widget}_#{f.name}", -> { where("people.data NOT LIKE '%#{f.name}%' OR people.data LIKE '%#{f.name}: \n%'") }
    end
end
```

Comment: What you are doing is basically reinventing the Entity Attribute Value (anti-)pattern. And the whole metaprogramming the class at runtime approach is very unlikely to pan out exactly because of class caching. Its feels very much like you are trying to shoehorn something into a relational database that does not belong and a document store like mongodb would be a better fit. if you decide that you want to go down this rabbithole use Single Table Inheritance to create different field classes instead of that enum and switch solution which is doing way to much in a single class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right that this is EAV, and it would definitely make sense to see if this project could be moved to MongoDB in the future.  Right at the moment, that's not possible. I can see STI would simplify things in the Field class

Comment: I'm not totally sure how I would approach this but instead of metaprogramming the class you have to actually do database queries and evaluate things on-the-fly when actually setting stuff or validating records or quering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by setting up the EAV system with STI:

```
module DynamicFields
  # Represents the normalized A in EAV
  class FieldType
    self.abstract_class = true
    self.table_name = 'field_types'
  end

  def self.exist?(name)
     FieldType.exist?(name: name)
  end
end

module DynamicFields
  class StringType < FieldType
  end
end

module DynamicFields
  class IntegerType < FieldType
  end
end

# more types ...

module DynamicFields
  # This is the V in EAV
  class FieldValue
    self.table_name = 'field_values'
    belongs_to :person # this is the E in EAV
    belongs_to :field_type # this is the A in EAV
  end
end

class Person
  has_many :field_types, 
    class_name: 'DynamicFields::FieldType'
  has_many :field_values, 
    class_name: 'DynamicFields::FieldValue'
end
```

There is a bit going on here but you basically have a `field_types` table with the normalized field types like for example:

```
id | type            | name            | required
1  | StringType      | display_name    | false
2  | IntegerType     | age             | false
```

The actual values are stored on the `field_values` EAV table:

```
id | field_type_id  | person_id    | value (JSON)   
1  | 1              | 1            | "Mr Loverman"
2  | 2              | 2            | 21
```

What you are doing with `missing_personal_email` is actually very much like [Rails Dynamic Finders](http://chrisholtz.com/blog/in-defense-of-dynamic-finders/) that ended up being axed from the framework and can be implemented though method_missing:

```
module DynamicFields
  module MissingFinders
    # name is the name of the method that was called
    def method_missing(method_name, *args, **kwargs, &block)
      return super unless method_name.start_with?('missing_')  
      self.joins(field_values: :field_type)
          .where(field_values: { 
             value: nil, 
             field_type: {
               method_name.strip('missing_')
             }
          }
      )
    end
  end
end
```

If its actually a good idea is quite questionable as it introduces a lot of potential bugs and performance problems. I would just write a normal method that takes parameters instead:

```
module DynamicFields
  module Scopes
    def missing_field(*fields)
       where(field_values: { 
         value: nil, 
         field_type: {
           name: fields
         }
       })
    end
  end
end
```

Yeah `Person.missing_field(:personal_email)` it not as magical as `Person.missing_personal_email` but magic always comes with a cost.